# Java enum with generic attributes

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have been trying to create enum that contains generic attribute, for example:

```
public enum SomeEnum {
    SOME_VALUE_1(SomeValue1.class),
    SOME_VALUE_2(SomeValue2.class);

    private final Class<T extends SomeValue> className;
}
```

`SomeValue1` and `SomeValue2` classes implement `SomeValue` interface. For some reason `<T extends SomeValue>` is marked with "Unexpected bound" error. If I replace `T` with `?`, there is no error. But it is still puzzling me why it is happening when I use `T`.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `T extends SomeValue` in this way, you are referencing a type variable `T` that isn't defined, and you aren't allowed to define a type variable there.  Only on type variable declarations are you allowed to define a bound such as `T extends SomeValue`.

On an interface or class, you could define `T` with the bound you want, but not on an `enum`.  Enums are not allowed to be generic in Java.

You are probably getting the same error on the constructor you haven't shown that accepts a `Class<T extends SomeValue>` to assign to `className`.  The same reason applies here too.

Using `? extends SomeValue` is an upper-bounded wildcard.  It basically means "a specific yet unknown type that is `SomeValue` or a subtype".  This is appropriate here, because all you care about here is that the `Class` is for `SomeValue` or some implementation class.

Comment: I am using Lombok, so didn't notice it in constructor, but it makes sense. Thank you very much for the explanation, now it is clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

`<? extends SomeClass>` and `<T extends SomeClass>` are two very different syntaxes.

The first is a *wildcard bound*, part of a [*type argument*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1):

```
TypeArguments:
  < TypeArgumentList >
TypeArgumentList:
  TypeArgument {, TypeArgument}
TypeArgument:
  ReferenceType 
  Wildcard
Wildcard:
  {Annotation} ? [WildcardBounds]
WildcardBounds:
  extends ReferenceType 
  super ReferenceType
```

The second is a *type bound*, part of a [*type parameter*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4):

```
TypeParameter:
  {TypeParameterModifier} Identifier [TypeBound]
TypeParameterModifier:
  Annotation
TypeBound:
  extends TypeVariable 
  extends ClassOrInterfaceType {AdditionalBound}
```

What's the difference between a type parameter and a type argument? A type parameter, like a method parameter, occurs at e.g. a generic class/method declaration:

```
class Foo<T extends SomeClass> {} // "T extends SomeClass" is a type parameter
class Bar<T> {} // "T" is a type parameter
```

This is analogous to method parameters:

```
void foo(int i) {} // "int i" is a method parameter
```

A type argument, like a method argument, occurs where you *use* a generic class/method. For example, in a field declaration:

```
Foo<? extends SomeClass> foo; // "? extends SomeClass" is a type argument
Bar<String> // "String" is a type argument
```

This is analogous to method arguments that you pass when you call a method:

```
foo(1); // "1" is a method argument
```

So really, using `T extends SomeClass` where you should use `? extends SomeClass` makes no sense. You are not declaring a new type variable here. You are merely constructing a generic type.